# Does AWS parameter store service fall under the PCI compliance?

Tags: pci-compliance, aws-ssm

The "AWS Services in Scope by Compliance Program" list does not contain AWS parameter store service. Is parameter service a PCI compliant one?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Parameter Store is part of AWS Systems Manager. AWS Systems Manager is PCI compliant.